# What's the use case? Typescript class with only static members vs object with properties

Tags: typescript

What's the benefit of this...

```
class Utils {
    static doSomething() {
        return 'something'
    }

    static doAnother() {
        return 'another'
    }
}
```

versus this...

```
const Utils {
    doSomething: () => 'something',
    doAnother: () => 'another',
}
```

Assuming `Utils` is never meant to be instantiated (it's just going to be a collection of methods), is there a reason to use one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming Utils is never meant to be instantiated (it's just going to be a collection of methods), is there a reason to use one or the other?

Its different ways of creating the same thing. There are others as well. Since its not meant to be instantiated, I would do the simple `const Utils` version.

## Other ways

e.g. `namespace`

```
namespace Utils {
    export function doSomething() {
        return 'something'
    }

    export function doAnother() {
        return 'another'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah from a consumer's perspective, they are the same thing. You'll use them the same say. As a library developer, isn't there a more concrete way to know which is better knowing that at runtime those different ways actually do the same thing differently?

Comment: The simple const version will perform best as its simpler on the runtime as well.

Comment: `As a library developer, isn't there a more concrete way to know which is better knowing` No. It's experience based. Always side with simplicity 